# Multiplying two lists in a sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum, multiplication

I have a formula (image attached) that I need to use. I have two lists, x and y. My issue is that I need to multiply these two lists in the formula for M. But it seems that I can not multiply lists in python. How can I code for M using two lists? Here is my current code

```
m = (1/D)sum((([(xi-xbar) for xi in x]))*([(yi*1) for yi in y]))
print('m',m)
```

I get the error "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'"

How do I multiply two lists, thanks!

[image: Formula]

Comment: Don't attach images. Please provide sample data and your expected result. [ask]

Comment: Not sure if I totally understood the requirements. But try `m = 1/D * sum((x[i] - xbar) * y[i] for i in range(len(x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do this.

`m=sum((xi-mean(x))*yi)`

You can try this.

```
from statistics import mean
x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[6,7,8,9,10]

mean_x=mean(x)

m=(1/D)*sum((i-mean_x)*j for i,j in zip(x,y))
c=mean(y)-(m*mean_x)
```

Comment: Thank your for your comment, it worked! I am trying to use what you have shown me here for another formula. The formula is d=yi-mxi-c. So I have `d = j-(m*i)-c for i,j in zip(x,y))
print('d',d)`But i'm getting invalid syntax. Any idea why?

Comment: Figured out they syntax, was just brackets. But now I have a new issue. So I have `d = (j-(m*i)-c for i,j in zip(x,y))
print('d',d)` But i'm getting d <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000027C60346A50> as an asnwer. Any idea why?

Comment: `d` is a generator here. Consume it with `list(d)`. Note: `d` can only be iterated *once* if it's generator. Use this instead `d = [j-(m*i)-c for i,j in zip(x,y)]` will make `d` a list. If this helped please accept this as answer and upvote.

Comment: Just one last follow up question, how do I now use d in another formula. Since i and j are used for x and y, what do I put in for d?

Comment: Probably should have mentioned what formula i'm using, delta                            m^2=((1/D)*((sum d^2)/n-2)). For code I have `(deltam)**2=((1/D)*(Sum d /(len(x)-2)))`. Not sure what to do about the list d.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the zip function in python to do pair 2 lists.

```
list_a=[1,2,3]
list_b=[4,5,6]
multiplied_ab=[]
for i,j in zip(list_a,list_b):
    multiplied_ab.append(i,j)
print(multiplied_ab)
```

Your result will be multiplication of the 2 lists like this:
[4,10,18]

You'll have to make sure that the length of the 2 lists match.

Then you can simply calculate the sum of the list by using the `sum()` function

Comment: Seems my code didnt come through, m = (1/D)sum((([(xi-xbar) for xi in x]))*([(yi*1) for yi in y]))
print('m',m)
I not only need to multiply the lists but also the other operations in the formula. I need to have m=1/D sum(list_x - xbar)*list_y. I have the values for D and xbar. So how can I minus xbar from the list_x then times it by list_y while taking the sum?